# Multiply all rows in a Pandas DataFrame by dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a `DataFrame` call it `one` like this:

```
non_multiply_col col_1 col_2
A Name           1     3
```

and a `dict` like this call it `two`:

```
{'col_1': 4, 'col_2': 5}
```

is there a way that I can multiply all rows of `one` by the values in `two` for the columns as defined by `two`'s keys so the result would be:

```
non_multiply_col col_1 col_2
A Name           4     15
```

I tried using `multiply`, but I'm not really looking to join on anything specific. Maybe I'm not understanding how to use `multiply` correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*mul/multiply* works fine if the dictionary is converted to a *Series*:

```
d = {'col_1': 4, 'col_2': 5}

df.mul(pd.Series(d), axis=1)

#   col_1   col_2
#0      4      15
```

In case you have more columns in the data frame than the dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'col_1': 1, 'col_2': 3, 'col_3': 4}])   
d = {'col_1': 4, 'col_2': 5}

cols_to_update = d.keys()  # you might need cols_to_update = list(d.keys()) in python 3
# multiply the selected columns and update
df[cols_to_update] = df[cols_to_update].mul(pd.Series(d), axis=1)[cols_to_update]
df

    col_1   col_2   col_3
#0      4      15       4
```

I happen to find this work as well, not sure if there is any caveat about this usage:

```
df[d.keys()] *= pd.Series(d)
```

Comment: Surely. Good luck with it.

Comment: So perhaps I've left out a critical part of my question here: I have more columns in my DataFrame than the ones that I would like to multiply on. I've updated my question.